# Why isn't my remote git repository picking up the changes that I'm pushing to it?

Tags: git, push, git-pull

Here's what I've done:

**1 - (Remote server)**

- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -a -m "Initial Commit"`

**2 - (Local computer)**

- `git clone root@URL:/path/to/repository` [image: pic1]
- Now I type: `git log` and successfully see the commit history on my local machine: [image: pic2]
- Great, all is well so far. Now to change a file locally... I change `resource/templates/default_site/_includes.group/header.html` and hit Save
- I now hit `git status` just to triple check that it sees that I changed a file, and it works: [image: pic3]
- I now hit `git commit -a -m "Test commit"` - success once again: [image: pic4]
- All is well so far, time to push my changes to the remote server with `git push origin master`: [image: pic5]
- So it seems to think that it pushed the changes to the remote branch successfully. Let me make sure by going back to the remote server...

**3 - (Back on remote server)**

- I check if it has the latest commit from my local repository with `git log` -- and I can very clearly see my test commit from a second before. So it successfully commited from my local repo -> the remote repo...

  [image: pic6]
- But if I open up `resource/templates/default_site/_includes.group/header.html` on the remote server, my change ISN'T in there!

What am I doing wrong here? Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have done everything except `checkout` the changes from your remote's repo to your remote's working directory.

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm new to git -- what's the command I want to use?

Comment: `git checkout master`